# Jmail is adding random ? marks to body of email

Tags: asp-classic, jmail

I am using ASP Classic Jmail.  The body is HTML and form driven.  I am getting random '?' marks scattered through the message of the email after being sent. I made sure there was no inadvertent HTML being created.  I did see that random "!" marks can be created if lines are too long... but I am not getting those.  No rhyme or reason to where they are being placed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong charset:

http://www.dimac.net/Products/w3Jmail/Version37/Reference/RefStart.htm#Charset

look for the charset method. If you are just sending English or some other western languages you can stick with the sample charset as in the documentation. Otherwise go for utf-8